# JdbcTemplate cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, compiler-errors, jdbctemplate

I am trying to hit the database using spring JdbcTemplate... I have added the required dependency spring-jdbc in pom.xml.. the required jar is successfully added to eclipse library...I can see it in maven dependency folder in eclipse...

But still, I am facing an issue with importing the class JdbcTemplate & hence unable to proceed further...

I am getting this error - JdbcTemplate cannot be resolved to a type

I had created a new project again in the eclipse... still having the same error....

Code :

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.wocs.services.inventory.model.Customer;


public class CustomerDAO implements CustomeryDAOIface{

       private DataSource dataSource;

       private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

       public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
          this.dataSource = dataSource;
          this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
       }

       public List<Customer> getManufacturers() {

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";

            List<Customer> customers  = 
                     getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
                    new BeanPropeMtyRowMapper(Customer.class));


        return customers;
    }
}
```

system & application configuration: 
OS: ubuntu 16.0.4
spring version - 5.0.3
tomcat 9 (also tried alternative tomcat 7)
jdk 91. (tried alternative 1.7, 1.8 too) 
Eclipse Oxygen 3

It will be very helpful for me if any one can give me the solution...

Comment: The compile time error is happening during your Maven build?   I'm using Gradle and spring-data 5.0.4 with Java 8 JDK and I have not had any trouble with JdbcTemplate.

Comment: How are you compiling your project? Have you run mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse? Is the name, package correct in the import statement and wherever you are using JdbcTemplate? Please share the code where you are getting the compilation error.

Comment: On eclipse, it automatically gets compile... I am not able to import the class JdbcTemplate... I have added the code. please check.

Comment: What is your spring configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- try to remove spring-jdbc folder from maven repository
- right click on project , maven , update project

Comment: I don't see any folder named spring-jdbc inside m2/repository/...please specify the path for local maven repository...

Comment: It's done... Thanks a lot... I spent almost a day on it.... You have given me a very nice solution... thank you once again....

Comment: could you explain me why did it happen so?... whether spring-jdbc has not downloaded successfully or due to any other specific reason?

Comment: it seems that your ide doen't update maven dependencies

Comment: Any gradle alternative solutions?..

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then update your project 
(right-click on the project)->Maven->Update project
Make sure you have an internet connection while updating.

It should resolve the error.